# Accuracy in naive bayes classification is 100%

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, naivebayes

I have a classification problem for which I want to do classification for class A, B, and C. I try to use naive bayes classifier and the accuracy is 100%, which I really doubt is not true. I have small dataset around 350, among that class A is 140, class B is 140 and rest are class C. Here is the code I used. Can anyone please provide me some suggestions on this?

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
X = feature_data_frame.values
y = label_data
import sklearn.preprocessing as preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.10)
gnb = GaussianNB()
y_pred = gnb.fit(x_train, y_train).predict(x_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hemanta, "which I really doubt is not true." - did you verify this by checking the predictions and the actual value? Since the dataset is very small, the model is susceptible to overfitting. You could try train-test-validation split, and even k-fold cross-validation. But please explore the dataset first to pick the best model accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I did. The predictions and the actual values are the same. Thanks for the suggestions. But  to my knowledge selection of the model is kind of hit and trail, how do you choose the best model based on the data you have? As it is a classification problem we need to choose among the classification models, but the best one is with the trail and error method right.